# how to connect to IBM Websphere MQ with a specific user using C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

i have to connect to MQ server from a client. Server MQ runs with a user "admin". how do i connect to sever from client with a specific user "admin" using .net? , i would be running the code with my local credentials. Is there a way to do this? I am using MQ server and client 8.0.0.6 , Win server 2008 R2. "Admin" user doesnt have any password in Server. I have used below code to connect with the user

update on this - now i have a userid and password , when tried to connect throws 2035 error.

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "10.136.232.46");
props.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName); 
props.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414); 
port number props.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "mqchluser");
props.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mqchluser");
props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT); 
MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,props );
```

Comment: Connecting as the user the MQ queue manager runs as is not a good idea as it means the application has full MQ administrator authority,  is this what you want?   If it is an application that only requires access to a subset of queues then you should create a user that is specific to the app and grant it access to the queues required.  This uses should have a password so that you can authenticate from the client by sending the id and pw.

Comment: I would need access to only read the queue in the MQ server. Adding another user is not in picture. Is there a way to connect to MQ server with user on which MQ server runs that is "Admin" from the client ? MQ server and client are on different machine but in the same network

Comment: i have used a user with userid and password , if i  now run i get 2035 error. What is it i am missing here?

Comment: Please add the details from the comment to on the answer below to your question and I'll write up an answer with the details.

Comment: You can format the code and errors in blocks by indenting 4 spaces, this is much more readable than it getting jumbled up in a comment.  Can you also check the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG to see why you are receiving a 2035.  It could be because the password authentication failed or it could be that you did not provide OAM permissions for the new user.

Comment: i have added the code in the question above . To find the logs from the queue manager , i do not have access. will take some time to fetch it. will update you shortly

Comment: Did you find out what error is logged in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG at the time you get a 2035?

Comment: when we tried to connect with user name and password it connected without any issue . I am not sure what the issue was the first time. Thank you for the help @JoshMc

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection authentication to authenticate as a specific user. In the MQEnvironment class there is a UserId and a Password attribute for this:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111180_.htm

But the queue manager you connect to needs to be configured properly too so it enables connection authentication and it uses the authenticated user id for authorization checks. And further the channel authentication records need to be configured to allow administrator connections.

Comment: Here the user in the MQ server does not have a password , it only has a username.When i use onlu user id , it shows null reference as there is no password. If i put any random password it doesn't authenticate the user.

Comment: if i a create a user and password for MQ server , should the access  be given to the server or to the Queue Manager for the connection to be successful ?